# How do I pass the app around function?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, go, firebase-authentication, jwt

In `main`, the app is started as such:

```
// ...

func main () {
    initializeAppDefault()
    go lib.GetData()
    http.HandleFunc("/_ah/somepoint", lib.SomeHandler)
// .. 

func initializeAppDefault() *firebase.App {
    // [START initialize_app_default]
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }
    // [END initialize_app_default]
    return app
}
```

In `SomeHandler`, I need the app which `initializeAppDefault` returns, to verify a JSON Web Token(JWT).

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Set content type:
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if r.Header != nil {
        ReqToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        splitToken := strings.Split(ReqToken, "Bearer")
        ReqToken = splitToken[1]
        fmt.Println(ReqToken)
        // Verify JWT
        // If it's invalid, return?

        verifyIDToken(app, ReqToken)
        // How do I pass the app in here?

func verifyIDToken(app *firebase.App, idToken string) *auth.Token {
// ...
```

My question is, when the app is initialized in the `main.go` file by invoking `initializeAppDefault()`, how do I pass it to the `SomeHandler` which handles requests at `/_ah/somepoint`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "passing an app" around. "App" usually refers to the compiled program, and any supporting files. That's not something that can be "passed around".

Comment: Ok, fair enough; But my question remains, how would I refer to it in the handler, then? I'm new to Go. Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: The normal way to pass arguments to a handler is to have it return a closure to the actual handler.

Comment: The function, `verifyIDToken`, takes `app *firebase.App` as one of two inputs, the other being the idToken itself. What should I pass into this function from `SomeHandler` to verify the token(in `ReqToken`)?

Comment: In the line where I call `verifyIDToken`, I need to pass the "app" somehow.. I'm asking how I get this from the context to pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to pass arbitrary dependencies into an HTTP handler function is by returning a closure:

```
func myHandler(a *Something, b *SomethingElse) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // The body of the handler here, using a and b
    }
}
```

Then you'll use it as:

```
http.Handle("/some/path", myHandler(a, b))
```

Comment: In my case, how would you pass the return value from `initializeAppDefault()` using your own example here?

Comment: `x := initializeAppDefault(); /* ... */ myHandler(x)`

Comment: Thank you. Learning a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Define new struct type with member of your `*firebase.App`:

```
type myapp struct {
    fbapp *firebase.App
    // here can be other common states and resources
    // like sessions, db connections, etc...
}
```

Define your handlers as methods of that type

```
func (ma *myapp) SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // here you have access to all members of myapp, including ma.fbapp
    // also you can use your lib.* funcs here
}
```

And in your main you need to create `myapp` and pass it to `http.HandleFunc`.

```
func main () {
    ma := &myapp{
        fbapp: initializeAppDefault()
    }
    go lib.GetData()
    http.HandleFunc("/_ah/somepoint", ma.SomeHandler)
```

This is a common pattern. Check out how i use it [in my interview task](https://github.com/someanon/yamc/blob/8bfa52eabc7d3c9781045ae01199e1900d5a454a/server/server.go#L16): pay attention how handlers are defined, [how they getting access to the common s.store](https://github.com/someanon/yamc/blob/8bfa52eabc7d3c9781045ae01199e1900d5a454a/server/server.go#L56) and [how main function inits all common resources, creates router and runs it](https://github.com/someanon/yamc/blob/8bfa52eabc7d3c9781045ae01199e1900d5a454a/main.go#L60).

Comment: When I use your syntax for `SomeHandler`, I lost access to it in the main function even though lib is imported.. How come?

Comment: @cbll what you mean "lost access"? Can you show more your code?

Comment: I had to move `SomeHandler` into the `main.go` where main is called. I can't use `lib.Somehandler` anymore, it doesn't recognize it from the lib package?